# New tables not showing up in MySQL Workbench Navigator

Tags: mysql-workbench

I've created a database on a local MySQL server with MySQL Workbench version 8.0 on Windows 10, but when I make a table in said database with a manually typed query

```
CREATE TABLE newtable (column1 INTEGER NOT NULL, column2 VARCHAR(30), PRIMARY KEY column1);
```

I can't see the table in the Navigator panel on the left hand side, even after right-clicking the schema and clicking Refresh All. However, the query was completed successfully according to the output. If I right-click the database and open the Schema inspector, in the Tables column, I can see the new table. I can even work with the new table with typed queries - I just can't seem to open the GUI. That is, until I restart Workbench, and then it shows up.

I tried creating a new table using the GUI, that is, right-click on "Tables" in the Navigator and then creating a new table, and that works as expected and the new table is visible in the Navigator.

Is this a bug in MySQL Workbench or am I doing something wrong? (I am very new to this, I'm still learning!)

EDIT: After rebooting my computer, the problem is gone and refreshing schemas works as expected. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: For me the new table shows up after manually refreshing the schema tree. Does the same happen when you fully qualify the table name?

Comment: *sigh* it didn't when I posted this question... but now it does. I guess a reboot fixed everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After rebooting my computer, the problem is gone and refreshing schemas works as expected. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯